# Populating variable in a script other than by means of env var

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

**Please note**: even though this question *mentions* MySQL and Docker, it really has nothing to do with either and should be answerable by any knowledgable bash scripter.

---

Rusty on my bash scripting here. I'm looking at the official [MySQL 8.0 Dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile) and see that it calls and runs a bash script called [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh). Looking at that script, it appears to (conditionally) run a [snippet of code that creates a database](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L133), if it doesn't already exist:

```
if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
  echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\` ;" | "${mysql[@]}"
  mysql+=( "$MYSQL_DATABASE" )
fi
```

I'm wondering where that script is expecting the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable be populated from. If it was expecting `MYSQL_DATABASE` to be an optional environment variable, I would have *expected* (from my admittedly rusty recollection) the if-conditional to look something like:

```
if [ -z "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
  ...
fi
```

I suppose it *could* be that `MYSQL_DATABASE` is expected to be a runtime argument to the script, but I'm leaning away from this as a viable option because the Dockerfile isn't passing any args to the script's invocation.

Can anyone help clue me in as to how I can populate `MYSQL_DATABASE` with the name of a DB (such as "`my_db`") so that when this script runs, the DB is created for me?

Comment: What the difference for the if condition if it's environment variable or variable defined in script, I mean if this check is working on variable defined in the script, why wouldn't it work on environment variables?

Comment: Thanks @Shmuel (+1) but I'm not understanding what you're trying to say. The question I'm asking here is: how would I populate `MYSQL_DATABASE` from outside the script, at runtime/invocation-time?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup : If a variable is not set explicitly in the script prior to its usage, and is supposed to contain a value, it must be an environment variable. Of course you, as the script author, could also decided to pass information to a script via the argument list or from a parameter file ... this is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as a shell script is concerned, an environment variable is just a variable that happens to be inherited from the environment, it doesn't change the *behaviour* of that variable.

So to understand what the code *does*, you don't need to know which "type" of variable it is, only that by that point in the code, there might be a variable with that name. You then need to know this fact about the `[` (aka `test`) command:

> `STRING`: equivalent to `-n STRING`

and

> `-n STRING`: the length of `STRING` is nonzero

So all `[ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]` means is "is the length of the `$MYSQL_DATABASE` variable more than zero at this point in the code?"

Whether this variable is expected "before" the script runs (e.g. preset as an environment variable) or calculated "inside" the script, you can only find out by reading through.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP (+1) so it _sounds_ like you're saying I could set that variable by running `./docker-entrypoint.sh --MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db`?

Comment: No, it's not option. You can inject a variable into the environment of a command by *prefixing* the command with an assignment, though: `MYSQL_DATABASE=mydn ./docker-entrypoint.sh`.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks @chepner (+1) I assume if I wanted to store `MYSQL_DATABASE=mydn` in a file, I would just need to `source` the file before running `./docker-entrypoint.sh`, correct?

Comment: Yes, but you also need to make sure the variable is actually exported: `export MYSQL_DATABASE=mydn`.

Comment: See also [MySQL option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html).